# How do I get bcvi installed and working (with Cygwin and Perl 5.8.8)?

Tags: vim, perl, vi, cygwin

I'm trying to install bcvi (under Cygwin), and there are apparently no directions that apply to this setup.  The directions at http://sshmenu.sourceforge.net/articles/bcvi/#installation state that bcvi is a standalone script with no non-core dependencies, but when I copied that script from the github repo it gave me this error:

```
Can't locate Pod/Text.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/msys 
 usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/msys /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8 
 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl.) at /c/Users/bzisad0/bin/bcvi line 1315.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /c/Users/bzisad0/bin/bcvi line 1315.
```

I'm not a Perl guy, but I understand that to suggest that there are unmet dependencies, and I'd rather not learn Perl and its ecosystem just to try to untangle this.

In case it's relevent, I first copied the script to the Linux server I intend to use it on, where I didn't get any such errors, but it seems to require you to run `bcvi --install` from your local machine, so I had to install it on my Windows machine (using the Git Bash shell, which AFAIK is just running Cygwin under the hood).  `perl --version` returns

```
This is perl, v5.8.8 built for msys
```

Is it possible to get this working on Windows?

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't have to do with POD, which is perls documentation format but perl modules, which are in fact like gems. I recommend trying this

```
curl -L http://cpanmin.us | perl - App::cpanminus
cpanm Pod::Text
```

There may be more dependenticies, so you may have to interpret them, simply replace the path `/` with `::` and remove the `.pm`

note: some distributors of perl strip modules out of core perl.